# In Exchange 2010/2013 co-existence, should I be seeing 2013 CAS servers when running Get-*VirtualDirectory Cmdlets?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, exchange-migration

We're in the middle of migrating from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2013.  I have 2 Ex2010 CAS and 2 Ex2013 CAS servers.  I understand changes have been made to the roles between 2010 and 2013 versions.  I also have 3 Ex2010 MB and 3 Ex2013 MB servers.

Everything seems to be operating normally.  I have created databases on the new MB servers, set virtual directory URLs, moved mailboxes as a test, etc.

One thing that I am seeing which is interesting is that when I run any of the Get-*VirtualDirectory Cmdlets, I see the 2 Ex2010 CAS servers listed, and the 3 Ex2013 MB servers listed, but I don't see the Ex2013 CAS servers.

When I go into ECP and look under virtual directories, I see all expected virtual directories for the 2010 and 2013 CAS servers.

Should I expect to see Ex2013 CAS servers in the output of the Get-*VirtualDirectory cmdlets?  If so, what could be causing these entries to be missing?

These are the Cmdlets I am referencing:

- Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory
- Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory
- Get-OABVirtualDirectory
- Get-ClientAccessServer
- Get-OWAVirtualDirectory

Comment: Can you try Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run the Powershell command while connected to one of the Exchange 2010 servers, I do not see the Exchange 2013 servers.

Using PowerShell on one of the new MB servers shows me the expected output for the above commands, which includes the new 2013 CAS servers. I am sure there is a logical explanation, but I have yet to find any documentation about why this is happening.

Comment: Microsoft recommends to switch to the newest CAS version as soon as possible.